# Proper way to handle OnClick event handlers that do basically the same thing?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Let's say I have a button that does something, and it's OnClick event handler is foo. then I have another button, with event handler bar, that sets some additional values and then does the same thing as foo. foo doesn't actually use any of it's arguments. What is the proper way to handle this?

Option 1:

```
protected void foo(object sender, EventArgs e) {
//does stuff
}

protected void bar(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
//does stuff
foo(null, null);
}
```

Calling foo with those nulls seems bad to me. Is it?

Option 2:

```
protected void foo(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
func();
}
protected void bar(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
//does stuff
func();
}
```

Having foo be nothing but a call to another function seems needlessly verbose though. This is clearer semantically though.

Not giving foo arguments doesn't seem to be an option, giving a compiler error.

Is there a better option I'm missing?

Comment: I don't see anything bad about option one. Or option two, really. Both are valid.

Comment: `Calling foo with those nulls seems bad to me. Is it?` That's what I've done for years and nothing bad has happened yet :)

Comment: I don't see a problem with either but if they're both doing the same thing you could wire both click events up to the same handler.

Comment: You could also put default value to the parameters as null (.net 4.0)  Then you could just call foo without passing parameters and know they will come in as null

Comment: @Smith.h.Neil Bar sets certain fields in the form before doing foo, so it does do extra stuff. I guess I could use one handler and then do an if based on what the sender was? But that seems like a more confusing option.

Comment: Oh yea sorry, I misunderstood. Don't do the single handler with an if on the sender. There's nothing wrong with your solutions but that one sounds pretty dirty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to go with one of the two options you listed.

I don't think it is bad to be a bit verbose sometimes and option two gives you a couple of small advantages.

- You will never have to do conditional checks to see if the parameters in foo are null.
- If more logic is added later, the code is already separated nicely making it easier just to add it to the correct place. (Like adding extra logic in the beginning of foo)

Answer (score 0):

When calling events that require no arguments consider using:

`foo(this, EventArgs.Empty);`

As Per the [EventArgs msdn description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.EventArgs(v=vs.110).aspx)

> To pass an object that does not contain any data, use the Empty field.

By convention event handlers should always include some sender and an EventArgs object.